# How to use class method in another file in a class python

Tags: python, class, inheritance, methods

I have file1.py, which has a class with  a method like below:

```
class c1:
    def m1(item):
        if item=="cool":
            return true
        return False
```

How can I in another python file, lets say file2.py, inherent this m1 from c1 in file1.py in a class,
I first import the class:

```
from file1 import c1
```

Can I do the inherence like below (using the same class and method name from file1.py in file2?)

```
class c1:
    def m1(item):
        c1.m1(item)
```

Comment: That would overwrite the `file1.c1` class definition with the `c1` class definition in file2. [Inheritance](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_inheritance.asp) might be something worth checking out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a couple of modifications to the files you've shown above, yes this would be possible. Here's my working version of this:

```
# file1.py

class c1:
    def m1(self, item):
        if item=="cool":
            return True
        return False
```

```
# file2.py

import file1

class c1:
    def m1(self, item):
        return file1.c1().m1(item)

test = c1()
print(test.m1("cool"))
```

Comment: @DoğanDündar I believe my answer does answer what the question is asking. The question is (paraphrased), "Can you have a method in a class reference another method in a class, where both methods and classes have the same name?"

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the same class name and function in file 2.

for example:

```
#file1

class c1:
    def m1(self, item):
        if item=="cool":
        return True
    return False
```

```
from file1 import c1
class another_class:
    def do_something(self, item):
        c1.m1(item)

print(another_class().do_something("cool"))
```

**Again, both do not need to have the same class and function name, but using different names will avoid confusion in long projects.**